# Python 3.x: Using string.maketrans() in order to create a unicode-character transformation

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-3.x

I would like to write the following code:

```
import string
frm = b'acdefhnoprstuw'
to  = 'אקדיפהנופרסתאו'
trans_table = string.maketrans(frm, to)
hebrew_phrase = 'fear cuts deeper than swords'.translate(trans_table)
```

The above code doesn't work because the `to` parameter to `string.maketrans(frm, to)` has to be a byte sequence, not a string. The problem is that byte sequences can only contain ASCII literal characters. Therefore I cannot make a transformation which translates English strings to Hebrew strings. The reason is that `string.maketrans()` retruns a bytes object.

Is there an elegant way to use the `string.maketrans()` and `translate()` functions (or equivalent functions that work with unicode) for my task?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use str.maketrans(), which takes two str as arguments.

```
>>> frm = 'acdefhnoprstuw'
>>> to = 'אקדיפהנופרסתאו'
>>> trans_table = str.maketrans(frm, to)
>>> hebrew_phrase = 'fear cuts deeper than swords'.translate(trans_table)
>>> hebrew_phrase
'פיאר קאתס דייפיר תהאנ סוורדס'
```

String.maketrans still existed in Python 3.1, but that's just because they missed moving it to bytes.maketrans() in 3.0. It was deprecated in 3.1 already and in 3.2 it is gone.